# If the given source is not conserved, then which gauge should we use in photon propagator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, propagator

The photon propagator in general gauge is 
$$D_F^{\mu\nu}=\frac{-g_{\mu\nu}}{k^2+i\epsilon}+\frac{\xi-1}{\xi}\frac{k^\mu k^\nu}{(k^2+i\epsilon)^2}.$$
In general textbook, the reason that the gauge-dependent part does not contribute is that 
if the source is conserved, i.e. $k^\mu j_\mu(k)=0$, then the gauge-dependent part $\frac{\xi-1}{\xi}\frac{k^\mu k^\nu}{(k^2+i\epsilon)^2}$ will not make contribution.

My question:

If the given source is not conserved, then which gauge should we use?
Because this question is physical and nontrivial and we could first give a distribution of electric current which is not conserved, then it seems that different gauge will give different answers. How to handle this puzzle?

Comment: If you're a beast at integrals, you can leave in $\xi$ and if it falls out by the end, you have a powerful check on the arithmetic, because any physical quantity cannot depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

The conservation of the source (actually it is the current that is conserved) and the gauge symmetry are very closely related. Actually it is very difficult (if not impossible) to have a vector particle (like the photon) couple to *anything* at all if that vector particle is not a gauge boson (and therefore couples to gauge-symmetric, i.e. conserved, currents only).

Anyway I am slightly puzzled by your positing of "electric currents which are not conserved". Where would one encounter that?